# How can I "restrict" the number of characters in a string on my index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails app I have a "Post" model, in the index page I'm showing all of my posts as "squares" with the title and a small excerpt. The size of each "square" is 250px wide.

Since some of the titles are longer than 250px, I want to be able to "restrict" the number of characters that are going to be shown in title on my "posts" index page.

Instead of "Frozen Dried Strawberry" have something like "Frozen Dried Stra.."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate

```
truncate(@post.title, :length => 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jason mentioned, the truncate helper function should work.

However, if you have html tags (links, etc.) in the text of this string, it might be worth looking into a gem or helper that will safely escape them, such as `truncate_html` gem.
https://github.com/ianwhite/truncate_html

For example: if it allows links, you don't want to truncate between the  tag and the  tag because it would cause heavily malformed html.